# How do I correctly configure nginx to work with rails on Ubuntu 16.04 on digital ocean

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails

I have decided to install latest ubuntu 16.04 system on the site I manage and it was a chain of disasters. I had problems with mysql server that I'm not sure are completely fixed, because sometimes I have mysql connection errors. I gave up on setting spam assasin. but I would like at least to make the website being served as before. I get these strange nginx errors that I do not understand. In the past I was able to succesfully deploy various rails apps without major problems. but here I am hopelessly stuck. Much of my website works, but some links don't. http://chrisbeard-images.com/photos?tag=Bridges

They seem to be fine on local development machine and were perfectly fine before I reinstalled the system.

$ tail log/nginx.error.log gives me errors i do not understand

```
2016/06/20 21:01:34 [info] 17909#17909: *41 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 86.22.165.132, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

$ tail log/nginx.access.log

> 86.22.165.132 - - [20/Jun/2016:20:48:24 -0400] "GET /photos?tag=Bridges HTTP/1.1" 500 643
>   "http://chrisbeard-images.com/tags" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux
>   x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"

$ cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
        client_max_body_size 2048M;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css text/comma-separated-values;
        upstream app_server { server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0; }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/chris/Rails/chrisbim2ree/shared/tmp/sockets/chrisbim2ree-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/chris/Rails/chrisbim2ree/current/public;
  access_log /home/chris/Rails/chrisbim2ree/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/chris/Rails/chrisbim2ree/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: It turns out it's a Mysql problem. I found this in production.log ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Expression #1

Comment: looks like it's an incompatibility between mysq 5.7 and old version of rails that I still using. But does my config look ok?

Comment: I have created a virtual machine where I try to mimic the production server. There I started with upstream config and started comparing with what I got. nginx.conf seems to be fairly the same as mine, but site-enabled/default has something that seems to be the culprit. I mean proxy_redirect off. This seems to be the reason why part of my site stopped working. however commenting it out and restarting production server didn't fix it. I have test server almost working. tomorrow I'll try to provide more information.